# Windows.security.cryptography API fails due to key length issues

Tags: .net, encryption, windows-8, encryption-symmetric

I've been trying to use the Windows.security.cryptography API in Windows 8 (Windows store app) for basic symmetric key encryption of a string (for now).

Looked into various samples online, but in all of them, the code fails with an unexpected key length exception for me.

```
static byte[] cKey = { (byte)'A', (byte)'B', (byte)'C', (byte)'D', (byte)'E' };
        static byte[] cIV = { (byte)'A', (byte)'B', (byte)'C', (byte)'D', (byte)'E' };
        public static string Encrypt(String guidOriginal)
        {
            IBuffer encrypted;
            IBuffer buffer;
            IBuffer iv = null;
            SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider algorithm = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm("AES_CBC_PKCS7");
            IBuffer keymaterial = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(cKey);  
            CryptographicKey key = algorithm.CreateSymmetricKey(keymaterial);
            iv = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(cIV);  
            System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
            buffer = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray( encoding.GetBytes(guidOriginal));
            encrypted = Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(key, buffer, iv);
            return CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(encrypted);
        }
```

^^ The above is one of the codes I tried (used a modified version of the code from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-ZA/winappswithcsharp/thread/b541a08a-d3cd-4e21-8d21-7ed80749cb23 ), which fails at

```
 CryptographicKey key = algorithm.CreateSymmetricKey(keymaterial);
```

With the exception: **ArgumentException**

Comment: What part of "Invalid key length" are you struggling with? All of the examples on the page you've linked to seem to be very careful to ensure that the key contains exactly 16 bytes. Your code creates a `cKey` with just 5 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

You must ensure your key block is exact 16,24 or 32 bytes.

Please refer to the wiki.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard

> AES is based on a design principle known as a substitution-permutation network, and is fast in both software and hardware.[6] Unlike its predecessor DES, AES does not use a Feistel network. AES is a variant of Rijndael which has a fixed block size of 128 bits, and a key size of 128, 192, or 256 bits. By contrast, the Rijndael specification per se is specified with block and key sizes that may be any multiple of 32 bits, both with a minimum of 128 and a maximum of 256 bits.